# Perl - dequeue a hash when processing multi-threaded

Tags: multithreading, perl, hash, queue

I've a very large hash-of-hash with upwards of 50,000 entries.  I want to process this multi-threaded due to time constraints.

Is it possible for each call to dequeue() to return the next item from the hash, and not the complete hash?  In the example below I want dequeue() to return just:

```
flintstones => {
    old_address => "0x1231234a",
    new_address => "0x1234234d",
    source      => "sym"
},
```

I can then process that in my thread whilst another thread dequeues another item from the hash until all items are processed.  My code example below.

If I need to change the storage format (HoH) that's not a problem. Perhaps an array of hashes would work?  Any help/pointer appreciated.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hoh = (
    flintstones => {
        old_address => "0x1231234a",
        new_address => "0x1234234d",
        source      => "sym"
    },
    jetsons => {
        old_address => "0x12712343",
        new_address => "0x12142344",
        source      => "sym"
    },
    simpsons => {
        old_address => "0x12f12347",
        new_address => "0x12a42348",
        source      => "dwarf"
    },
);


my $href = \%hoh;
my $queue= Thread::Queue->new($href);

my $t = threads->create('start_sub');
my $result = $t->join;

sub start_sub {
   print "items on queue = " . $queue->pending() . "\n";

    while( $queue->pending() ) {

         my $item = $queue->dequeue_nb();

         #
         ## dequeue_nb returns undef when queue empty
         if( $item ) {

            print "Doing work in thread " . threads->tid() . " on:\n";

            print Dumper($item);
            print "Done =====================\n"
         }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Think I've solved this with `my $queue= Thread::Queue->new(keys %hoh);`.  Basically load the keys of the hash into the queue and then each thread can work on an individual item...

Answer (score 0):

But it will be better if you use reference instead of hash. Use an arrefref that contain hashrefs. That would be more efficient.

This for your current code.

```
sub dequeue_nb{
  my $key_of_first_item = (keys %hoh)[0];#random order
  my $item = $hoh{$key_of_first_item};
  delete  $hoh{$key_of_first_item};
return $item;
```

regards,

Comment: dequeue_nb is from module Thread::Queue [link](http://perldoc.perl.org/Thread/Queue.html#BASIC-METHODS). Not sure redefining that function is what I want to be doing here...